# problema al insertar en oracle c#

Tags: c#, oracle, insert, oracle-19c

Tengo el siguiente código en c#

```
            string strInsert = string.Empty;

            strInsert="INSERT INTO Articulos" ;
            strInsert = strInsert + "(ID,Detalle,Precio)";
            strInsert = strInsert+ "VALUES (:identificador,:descripcion,:total)";


            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_conexionOracle))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = strInsert;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("identificador", OracleType.VarChar, 10).Value = contador;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("descripcion", OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value = desc;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("total", OracleType.Number).Value = total;
              
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
```

El problema que tengo es cuando mi variable "desc" trae un valor muy grande lanza una excepción de ***ORA-12899: el valor es demasiado grande para la columna***
¿Hay alguna forma de evitar la excepción?
En otra tabla me pasaba lo mismo, y con solo agregarle el tamaño al parámetro se soluciono, me recorta el texto y lo inserta, no entiendo por que en esta no, ¿Tendrá algo que ver que el string de la otra tabla es una sola cadena de caracteres y en esta la variable contiene espacios?

**Actualización**: Ya encontré el problema, el cual es que mi variable es por ejemplo

desc="impresión de planillas"

c# lee el acento como un solo carácter entonces si necesita recortar el texto lo hace correctamente al tamaño que le indico en el parámetro, pero al pasarlo a oracle, oracle me dice que estoy mandando un carácter de mas porque toma el acento como si fueran dos caracteres. Veré si hay alguna solución que no sea acortar el tamaño del parámetro (porque afectaría a todas mis "desc" aun y cuando no tengan acentos).

Gracias por leerme.

Answer (score 1):

Si envías un `string` más largo que la definición del campo, siempre fallará. La única solución es recortarlo.

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("descripcion", OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value = desc.SubString(1,80);
```

Comment: Y si se usara un CLOB, en vez de varchar?

Comment: Efectivamente el problema no está en C#, el problema lo tienes en la definición del campo de Oracle. Si allí aumentas el número de caracteres admitidos, asunto solucionado. Esto no quita que en la inserción desde C# siempre debas tener un control de lo que se inserta. Un CLOB no creo que sea una buena solución si el 99% de inserciones tienen menos de 80 caracteres.

Comment: si, el control desde c#, es porque la bd es del cliente, por lo tanto no le puedo meter mano, y soy yo el que debe adaptarse a sus reglas de negocio